# Copying a jmp script from one table to another breaks the script

Tags: sas-jmp

I am running multiple data analysis scripts with are often oneway analyses or t-tests.

I have written or generated many of these myself but I have run into a recurring problem.

I will often generate the code while on one data table and then when I paste it to another data table with the same headings the script replaces single or multiple variables with "As Column()"

So if I have this:
Oneway(
Y( :"parameter 1" ),
X( :"parameter 2" ),
Each Pair( 1 ),
Means( 1 ),
Mean Diamonds( 1 ),
SendToReport(
Dispatch( {}, "Oneway Anova", OutlineBox, {Close( 1 )} ),
Dispatch(
{"Means Comparisons", "Comparisons for each pair using Student's t"},
"LSD Threshold Matrix",
OutlineBox,
{Close( 1 )}
),
Dispatch(
{"Means Comparisons", "Comparisons for each pair using Student's t"},
"Connecting Letters Report",
OutlineBox,
{Close( 1 )}
)
)
)

I end up with this non-functioning code after pasting it
Oneway(
Y( :"parameter 1" ),
X( As Column() ),
Each Pair( 1 ),
Means( 1 ),
Mean Diamonds( 1 ),
SendToReport(
Dispatch( {}, "Oneway Anova", OutlineBox, {Close( 1 )} ),
Dispatch(
{"Means Comparisons", "Comparisons for each pair using Student's t"},
"LSD Threshold Matrix",
OutlineBox,
{Close( 1 )}
),
Dispatch(
{"Means Comparisons", "Comparisons for each pair using Student's t"},
"Connecting Letters Report",
OutlineBox,
{Close( 1 )}
)
)
)

Another issue that happens is the original working code will sometimes not open correctly when run directly but it will work if I click edit and can see the code.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly? I am running JMP 15.0.0

TLDR: I tried to paste code from one data table to another with the same headings. I expected it to work but it broke in an unexpected way.